# Add row to column to CSV from variable list

Tags: list, powershell, csv, append

I've been fighting for over an hour for something that seems simple to me ... But I can not do it

Explanation :

I import a CSV who look like this, he's empty :

```
DAYS | PC1 | PC2
```

And i have a Variable "**$Days**" who look like this :

```
PS C:\Users> $Days
12/02/2019
13/02/2019
14/02/2019
15/02/2019
16/02/2019
```

**All i want is to add every line to the "Days" column**...

Like :

```
   DAYS    | PC1 | PC2
12/02/2019 |     |
13/02/2019 |     |
14/02/2019 |     |
15/02/2019 |     |
16/02/2019 |     |
```

I try something like :

```
Foreach ($row in $Days){
    $CSV.Days = $row
}
```

But he tell me that the property "Days" is not found.

i also try something like this :

```
$CSV | Select-Object @{Name='Days';Expression={$forearch ($row in $Days){$row}}},*
```

But no result again, i don't know what i'm doing wrong...

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: If your CSV really looks like that your first issue might be you need to use `-delimiter '|'` with `Import-CSV`

Comment: No, it's ok in reality it look like : "days";"pc1";"pc2" and i use -Delimiter ";"

Comment: `$Days| ForEach-Object{[PSCustomObject]@{DAYS=$_;PC1="";PC2=""}}`

Comment: @LotPings can you propose an answer, because if not, the question will still unanswered and you wrote a solution ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that the file is empty thus no properties are generated for $CSV

A simple solution is generating the $CSV by iterating $Days and building a `[PSCustomObject]`

```
$Days = @'
12/02/2019
13/02/2019
14/02/2019
15/02/2019
16/02/2019
'@ -split '\r?\n'

$CSV = $Days | ForEach-Object{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        DAYS = $_
        PC1  = $NULL
        PC2  = $NULL
    }
}

$CSV
$CSV | Export-Csv .\YouNameIt.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, a shorter version:

```
$CSV-out = $csv | ForEach-Object{[PSCustomObject]@{DAYS = $_}}|Select days, PC1, PC2
```

$csv is a list of values.  Similar to

```
$csv = @("12/02/2019","13/02/2019","14/02/2019","15/02/2019","16/02/2019")
```

If you then do a $CSV | FT

```
    DAYS       PC1 PC2
    ----       --- ---
12/02/2019         
13/02/2019
14/02/2019
15/02/2019
16/02/2019
```

You don't have to include a custom object just to add fields.  You can do a

> select

and it will add them for you as well.